# Strange behavior of the Controller_Plugin

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, request

In this example I want increase the session variable called "test" by one each time it enter to the controller. If comment the content of the method preDispath works fine but with this precise example, the session variable "test" increase in 3 or 5 each time.
I use Zend Framework 1.11.4

Why??? I hope you understand my question.

Remember this example is only to show the strange behavior of the method preDispatch

My plugin

```
class App_Plugins_Permisos extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{
    public function  __construct(){}
    public function  preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $request->setModuleName('default');
        $request->setControllerName('index');
        $request->setActionName('index');        
    }
}
```

My bootstrap

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap{
    protected function _initSession(){
        Zend_Session::start();
    }
    protected function _initPlugins(){
        $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
        $this->frontController->registerPlugin(new App_Plugins_Permisos());
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
    public function init(){}
    public function indexAction(){
        $s = new Zend_Session_Namespace('test');
        if(isset($s->test)){
            $s->test++;
        }else{
            $s->test = 1;
        }
        Zend_Debug::Dump($s->test);
        die();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried to replicate this problem, but I cannot. For me it works as expected (ZF 1.11.0).

Comment: with browser make your test? in my case work fine in ie8 but not in chrome and firefox 4

Comment: I use chrome 8 in Linux Mint 10.

Comment: Are you pushing other actions unto the action stack?

Comment: Only have one action in all project (indexAction from IndexController). Install new Zend Project and only have 1 plugin (Permisos), 1 Controller with 1 action.

Comment: Also try to set the request in another action and have the same problem. If i want redirect from the plugin to another action for example anotherAction (in IndexController) make many request (21 request). This i check with firebug. My code to make the redirection is `if($request->getActionName() != 'another'){
            
            $r = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
            $r->gotoSimpleAndExit('index', 'another', $request->getModuleName());
        }`

Comment: sorry my mistake in the last comment. In the "gotoSimpleAndExit" should be ('another', 'index', $request->getModuleName()). With this change dont have many request but i have the same problem from beginning

Comment: preDispatch executed on every dispatch loop iteration, effectively  overriding specified controller/action on forwarding or error.

Comment: but apparently the action from the controller runs in background more than one time. I dont know why does this. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Try it putting in .ini resources.frontController.plugins.foo = "My_Plugin_Foo"

If works tell me! Tnks